# findOne doesn't get any record

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

```
login: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.param('username');
        var password = req.param('password');

        User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
            if (err || !user) {
                return res.status('401').send("User with username \"" + username + "\" not found. Are you registered?");
            }
        ...
```

Gives me `undefined` for the `user` object and I always end up in the error statement. The `username` variable has the correct value. The method, where I create records, works (so my connection with the DB is alright), and when I look into the DB, the record is there, with all the correct data.

I also tried `User.find().where({username: username}).exec(function (err, user) {` with no success...

Any suggestions about where can I look into (debugging or smth) or what might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Side note: Express' [`req.param()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param) has been deprecated and may be removed in a future release. You should be referencing [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params), [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query), and [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body) directly.

Comment: Have you inspected the `err` provided by `.findOne()` for any possible details (e.g. `console.error('Error', err);`)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, the problem was in the model declaration. Your hint pointed me in the right direction. `err` gives `Details:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'users.passports' in 'field list'`. I will post an answer with an explanation, for other people's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan's comment to inspect `err` pointed me in the right direction. My `User` model was as follows:

```
attributes: {
        // Relations
        passports: {
            model: 'Passport'
        },
//... other attributes
```

and I also have the relation `belongsTo` declared in the `Passport` model. The `err` was giving `Details: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'users.passports' in 'field list'`, and of course in my `user` table in the database I did not have the `passports` column.

Conclusion: I had unnecessary entity relation declaration in the `User` model. This was working fine with `MongoDB`, but apparently with `MySQL` things quite different.